# Remove jump/jutter at end of slideDown() animation

Tags: jquery, slidedown

To start off with I know theres another post on the same topic but the answer for that does not work for me...

I am creating a services panel for my website: http://jagdogweb.com/ and at the end it has visible jerk at the bottom left of each pane...

Please Help...

http://jagdogweb.com/#services

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with CSS:

```
BODY {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The jump is occurring because the scrollbar is disappearing depending on the page height. This CSS rule will ensure that pixels are always shown for the scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work if you visit, http://jagdogweb.com/#services now you will se it's exactly the same...

Comment: When I visit the site it's completely different - smooth animation, no jerking motion. I think we may be seeing different effects. Looks great from here! (Chrome, FF)

Comment: Are you looking at the left side? because the right side is nice and smooth when the left side is jerky...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the element for slideDown is hidden and/or has padding. To solve this, ensure is not hidden so that the **height for animation can be calculated easily** by jQuery. To do this, wrap the element in parent DIV with

`height:0;overflow:hidden;`

So that the element you want to slideDown is hidden but not with CSS hidden, and it's height which is still at 100% can be used for jQuery animation in slideDown. Instead of slideDown, you can animate the parent element (which has height:0) to the child's full height.

Like this:

```
   $('.slideToggler').on('click', function() {
        var n = $(this).next();
        var h = n.find('.slidePanel:nth-child(1)').height();
        if(n.height() > 0) {
            n.animate({height:0});
        } else {
            n.animate({height:(h+padding)});
        }
    });
```